# Highest score when rolling three of a kind to score

Tags: probability, dice

Here is the game:

- You are rolling 6 six-sided dice
- each dice has the faces: 1, 2, 3, X, X, X (X sides don't matter)
- After you roll them all once, you can choose to pick up one or more and reroll them. You then can choose to pick up one or more dice and reroll a second time.
- If you get 1,1,1, you will score 1 point. 2,2,2, is two points, and 3,3,3, is three points
- Additional matches after the three-of-a-kind do not change your score. This means that 3,3,3,X,X,X AND 3,3,3,3,X,X both only score 3 points.
- No other combinations score any points, only three-of-a-kind.  This means that if you don't have at least one triplet, you won't score any points.

On my first roll, I do not get any triplets or pairs of numbers (for example  1,2,3, X, X, X), but one of the numbers is the number 3. Should I hold the 3 and try for more 3s in my rerolls? Or, am I better off rerolling all of the dice?

Comment: How could it be better to re-roll the $3$?  I'd have thought the ambiguous cases were things like $1,1,1,3,X,X$.  Should you re-roll any of the $1's$ in that case?  You risk that one point, but you have a high probability of getting triple $3's$.

Comment: The situation I was posing was something like 1,2,3, X, X, X (no triplets or pairs). Do you keep the 3 and reroll the other 5, or are you better off rerolling all 6

Comment: As I say, I can't imagine why you think giving up the $3$ is a good idea.  In that particular case, there are, of course, multiple options.  You could keep just the $3$, or the $3$ and the $2$ or the $3, 2,1$.  Easy enough to just check the expected results of each move.  You can also compare that to the case where you reroll all $6$, for completeness.

Comment: Should say:  just as point of clarification, is $2,2,2,3,3,3$ worth $5$ points? $3$ points?  $0$ points?  Your rule "no other combinations score any points, only three-of-a-kind" contradicts the rule that says "additional matches after the three-of-a-kind do not change your score".  The former rule would say that $3,3,3,3,3,3$ is worth $0$ but the latter rule says it is worth $3$.

Comment: "no other combinations score any points, only three-of-a-kind" was meant to imply that if the roll doesn't have at least one triplet, there wouldn't be any score.   "additional matches after the three-of-a-kind do not change your score" means 3,3,3,3 would still only be worth three. 2,2,2,3,3,3 would be worth 5, and 3,3,3,3,3,3 would be worth 6 (two triplets)

Comment: That's clear, thank you.  I suggest editing your post to reflect that (those examples settle the rules, I think).  I do not think the rules in your post were stated clearly, so it's worth the clarification.

Comment: As a general comment:  while this game is simple enough so that any given case can be handled analytically, it is often the case that it's best to simulate these things.  Just let a computer play it a few thousand times.  When you see, for instance, televised poker games with running probabilities displayed on the screen, those are all computed by sampling.

Comment: @lulu: Are you sure? How do you know that? Why wouldn't they compute them exactly?

Comment: @joriki  Pretty sure.  For Texas Hold Em, with some exposed cards communally available, it's not as simple as counting good hands (as it can happen that some of my paths to a strong hand inadvertently give you a path to an even better one).  For straight draw poker, it's easy enough to get closed solutions.

Comment: @lulu In Texax Hold'Em, with three community cards exposed, there are at most $\binom{45}{2}=990$ possible outcomes for the remaining two cards. The probabilities are computed exactly by considering all possible outcomes.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Absolutely.  I ought to have included brute force enumeration as a method.  Preferred method, when it makes sense.